# List posts by wordpress number

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm breaking my head to make this code work, see.

I can list my wordpress articles by letter.

But I can't do the same so that it shows articles that start with numbers.

See my code

```
    <ul>

 <?php
    //get all post IDs for posts beginning with cap B, in title order,
    //display posts
    $first_char = '0';
    $postids=$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT      ID
    FROM        $wpdb->posts
    WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->posts.post_title,1,1) = %s
    ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title",$first_char)); 

    if ($postids) {
    $args=array(
      'post__in' => $postids,
      'post_type' => ' ',
      'tag' => 'anime-dublado',
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
    );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
     echo ' '. $first_char;
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

      
<style>

.thumbnail{

position: 
z-index: 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
background-color: 
z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
position: fixed;
margin-top: 190px;
background-color: #d3d5d9;
padding: 5px;
left: -1000px;
border: 0px dashed gray;
visibility: hidden;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
border-width: 0;
padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/
visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 360px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */

}
</style>

<li>
<div class="manga-body">
<div class="thumb">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); }?>





<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
<?php echo catch_that_image(52, 50) ?>
<span>
<?php echo catch_that_image(auto, auto) ?>
</span>
</a>

</div>

<div class="manga-list">
<h2> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
</div>

<div class="" style="font-weight: margin-top: 20px;">

<div class="waktu"></div>
</div>
</div>
</li>


  <?php
      endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    }
    ?>


</ul>
```

I already tried to change that part $ first_char = '0-9'; for only one number but only 1 article appears.

I would like the code to show all articles that start with numbers only.

I could get it to work if I could put in that code $ first_char = '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'; but I can't do that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work:

`$first_char = "('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')";`

And in the SQL query change "**=**" for "**IN**"

`WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->posts.post_title,1,1) IN %s`

Comment: Thanks for responding, but it didn't work.

My code only works if I enter only one number, for example "0".

Comment: Do you mean post retrieving or presentation? I only saw now that you use `$first_char` inside the while loop, that would need some tinkering too.

Comment: Your code and had no effect.

My code only works if I leave only one number

Comment: If is that so, maybe you can wrap your code in a for loop going from 0 to 9 supplying the desired value for `$first_char` on each iteration.

Comment: I am very lay at doing this, could you show me an example?

Comment: Sure https://gist.github.com/diogobruno/450df0e5b647510cb87c6976b36381c7

Comment: I tested the code, but worpdrees displays the error There is a critical error on your site.

Comment: Don't know if got it to work but updated the [solution](https://gist.github.com/diogobruno/450df0e5b647510cb87c6976b36381c7) because it was simple. But you need to put some work in your php/wordpress studies.